# Background process in php

Tags: php, mysql, timer

my query starts with a great confusion so please help me out

I m working on Movie ticket booking project. Where i want to block the selected seats for 7 minutes til user makes an payment.

What i am doing is? whenever user selects seat & proceeds furthur then i m adding those seats to "blockedseats" table so that no one can access those seats & at the same time timer should start in background.. If user makes an payment then those seats are allocated to him ..if he fails to do payment within 7 minutes then the blocked seats will be released means i will remove them from table.

Idea is very simple but confused to proceed furthur.

please please please help...

Comment: what exactly is the problem?

Comment: i don't know how to start timer which will run exactly for 7 minutes in background ... actually i hvn't used 7 minute timer in my code....

Comment: Not providing an answer because the question is too vague as it is, but I feel like you should start by implementing your `blockedseats` table, or even adding a field to your seat table giving the status (`free`, `blocked`, `booked`). 

As for scheduling switching from `blocked` to `free` after 8 minutes, several solutions exist but if you're on a Unix environment, a CRON job could work. Apparently MYSQL also has an event scheduler, which I am not familiar with : http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/

Comment: I m working in unix environment.Yes CRON job can solve my issue... but i don't have any idea how to set cron job automatically using php code. Thank you guyz ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a timer. Timestamp the blockedseats record. If the user makes a payment within seven minutes, allow the transaction through. If the user attempts payment after seven minutes, refuse the transaction and remove the record from the blockedseats table.

If another user attempts to book the seats, check the blockedseats table. If the block has expired, refresh with a new timestamp for the new user. If the block is still active (within seven minutes) refuse the booking request.

The blockedseats table can be cleaned up with a cron script at an apppropriate interval. Say every hour, every day? to suit your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a linux server, please take a look into cronjob. A simple algorithm would be to store the timestamp at which seat was blocked along with the seat number.

Run the cronjob every minute. Check if the current timestamp is within 7 minutes of the blocked seat or not. Remove those which are not within 7 minutes range from current timestamp. A maximum tolerance of 59 sec is introduced with this method. You need to make a compromise between error tolerance and load to your server.